# Linear operators problems

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I V is reflected in the line y=3x  calculate $[$s_3x$]_B$

How would I start this question?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  To find the matrix in standard coordinates, use the reflected images of standard basis vectors as columns

Comment: Do you know how to find a matrix that corresponds with a transformation?

Comment: I’m not 100% sure is there a certain why of doing that?

Comment: Would I get a matrix reading (1,0,0,3) reading left to right? I’ve multiplied the y Cordinate by 3?

Comment: @Ellie Does scaling the second column by three correspond to a reflection across the line $y=3x$? Do you know what the columns of a matrix represent in terms of the transformation they describe? You may wish to ponder J.W. Tanner's comment -- he's already given you the answer.

Comment: I remember doing this at a level but I’m having a mind blank about it, I’m trying to research how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to apply the operation to the standard basis.

$s_{3x}((1,0)^T) = {1 \over 5}(-4,3)^T$, $s_{3x}((0,1)^T) = {1 \over 5}(3,4)^T$ (this takes a little straightforward 
algebra).

So, in the standard basis, the matrix is ${1 \over 5}\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 3 \\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense can I ask how you get the -4 and 4?

Comment: Reflect the point $(1,0)^T$ in the line $y=3x$ to get the point $(-{4 \over 5}, {3 \over 5})$ and similarly for the point $(0,1)^T$.

Comment: Ok just trying to get my head round where the numbers have come from thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a point (a,b). Find the reflection (a',b') of (a,b) in the line y=3x. Now write
v as the column vector with elements a and b. Do the same for (a',b'),turning it into a column-vector v'. Define M as the 2x2 matrix such that v'=Mv. M is the matrix you need.
You can do more-or-less the same for an arbitrary line cx+dy+e=0, except that then you get an affine transformation, which is more general.

Comment: Right so I found my reflection matrix is that equal to $[$s_3x$]_B$?